# How to change the start path of SystemDialogInput

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories

It seems that every time the start directory of `SystemDialogInput` is always the same, is it possible to set the start directory to the last used directory?

For example:

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]
```

[image]
will start from the "Documents" directory, if I change to other directory and select some file, and run the second input dialog

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]
```

it forgets the directory I chose in the first `SystemDialogInput` and starts from "Documents" directory again. Is it possible to set `SystemDialogInput` to always remember the last used directory?

Comment: Use the second argument of `SystemDialogInput`, and store the path in some variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simple do something like this:

```
file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]

SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", DirectoryName@file]
```

and your directory is the last one you've visited.

Comment: it's interesting. at first i started to write a `RegularExpression` and failed and then suddenly this nice function reared up...probably to often reinventing the wheel.